# Is there any way API can be called and the response can be used before in constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, constructor

I am calling an api using async await and the data returned from this api needs to be passed to one variable which is initialized in constructor

But the api returns data after the constructor initializes.

Can someone please suggest solution for this.

Comment: please post the code.

Comment: Use `useEffect` if your component is functional or `componentDidMount` if your component is class-based.

Comment: construct the object after you got the response, not before.